# How to have an external function (in javascript) call on an ID in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I keep getting errors when debug, and I can't find a discrepancy between my code and the YouTube tutorials I've been following.

When I run the code it shows an error next to all of my variables that call a function in my JS file.

`app.js`:

```
button.onclick = function(){   
  var content = document.getElementsById("content");
  var button = document.getElementById("showmore");

  if(content.className == "open") {
    button.innerHTML = "If you'd like to come click here to find out the address";
    content.className = "";
    button.innerHTML = "Show More";
  } else {
     content.className = "open";
     button.innerHTML = "Show Less";
  }
}

function changeColor(newColor) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('para');
  elem.style.color = newColor;
}
```

HTML (image and CSS removed in order to make it more readable):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>  <!-- for mega data-->
        <title> You're invited!</title>
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <h1>Sal and Cheong-a are getting married! </h1>
        <h2> Would you like to come to our wedding?</h2>
   <img src=/>
       <h2> Our favorite Poem</h2>

        <div id="content">
            I don’t love you as if you were a rose of salt, topaz,   
            or arrow of carnations that propagate fire:   
            I love you as one loves certain obscure things,   
            secretly, between the shadow and the soul.

            I love you as the plant that doesn’t bloom but carries   
            the light of those flowers, hidden, within itself,   
            and thanks to your love the tight aroma that arose   
            from the earth lives dimly in my body.

            I love you without knowing how, or when, or from where,   
            I love you directly without problems or pride:
            I love you like this because I don’t know any other way to love,
            except in this form in which I am not nor are you,   
            so close that your hand upon my chest is mine,   
            so close that your eyes close with my dreams.

            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>  

            Join us at 500 Easthampton Rd, <br> Holyoke, MA 01040 <br>
            The Log Cabin<br>
            September 7th 2020.
        </div>

        <a id="showmore">If you'd like to come click here to find out the address.</a>

        <p id="para">Some text here</p>

        <button onclick="changeColor('blue');">blue</button>
        <button onclick="changeColor('red');">red</button>

        <script src = "app.js"></script>    
    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: What is the *exact* error message that you are getting?

Comment: JS uses three `===`, not two

Comment: @Ryan Actually, JS uses two and three. Two is equality with conversion and three is strict equality.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - Ah, I see. Thx for the clarification.

Comment: You simply misspelled `document.getElementsById("content");`, should be `getElementById` w/o the `s` in `Element`

Comment: `button`, the very first word in your script, is undefined.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I'm new to "Bracket". I'm not sure how to see a readable error message. I simply see X's. Otherwise, I would, but I will try to find out how.

Comment: @SalvatoreDePalma You're supposed to check the console in the browser, while looking at the page. Press F12 to open the developer tools, then go to the console tab. Refresh the page to see the errors.

Comment: @LGSon, thank you. The same problem exists even when I get rid of the S. None of the actions (methos/functions?) are working.

Comment: This seems to be the error message: 

/LiveDevelopment/Inspector/Inspector.js:262 GET http://127.0.0.1:9222/json net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 2):

First, your `click` callback function declares the variable `button` ***after*** you are trying to use it:

```
// You haven't declared "button" yet!
button.onclick = function(){   
  var content = document.getElementsById("content");
  var button = document.getElementById("showmore"); // <-- Here's where you try
```

And, the method is called `.getElementById()`. You have:

```
var content = document.getElementsById("content"); // <-- Misspelling!
```

And (FYI), don't use `.innerHTML` to get/set text that doesn't contain any HTML, that's a waste of processing resources. For non-HTML strings use `.textContent`.

So, you need:

```
// Get your DOM references first (and just once):
var button = document.getElementById("showmore");
var content = document.getElementById("content");

// Then, you can use them:
button.onclick = function(){   
  if(content.className == "open") {
     button.textContent = "If you'd like to come click here to find out the address";
     content.className = "";
     button.textContent = "Show More";
   } else {
     content.className = "open";
     button.textContent = "Show Less";
   }
};
```

Comment: I literally copied and pasted your answer and the error messages are still there. But thank you so much, I've spent too long on this, so I think I'm going to change it.

Comment: This is the STRANGEST thing ever. So after I copied the edited code that you had  I started a new project - I made a new HTML, CSS, and JS file for shits and giggles. After I did that it started to work. So thank you so much!

The error messages keep appearing too, even though it's working. I think there's something wrong with the way I downloaded bracket.

Comment: @SalvatoreDePalma Don't forget to mark this as "the" answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the button by ID, BEFORE you attach a click handler to it:

You have

```
button.onclick = function(){   
var content = document.getElementsById("content");
...
```

You need

```
var content = document.getElementById("content");
var button = document.getElementById("showmore");

// Check here: we use the reference to the button AFTER we get it from the page.
button.onclick = function(event) {
  if(content.className == "open") {
     button.innerHTML = "If you'd like to come click here to find out the address";
      content.className = "";
      button.innerHTML = "Show More";
   } else {
      content.className = "open";
      button.innerHTML = "Show Less";
} }
```